# problems selecting max of an avg in SQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, average

I don't why I encountered in a stupid problem selecting records with max avg in SQL.

The table in question is generated by this query:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM (SELECT MATRDOC AS TEACHERID
         FROM DOCENTE
         WHERE MATRDOC NOT IN (SELECT MATRDOC
                               FROM CORSO
                               WHERE AREA <> 'BASI DI DATI')) DOC,
        (SELECT C.CODCORSO AS COURSEID, 
                MATRDOC AS TEACHERID, 
                AVG(NUMSTUDENTI) AS GVA
        FROM CORSO C, LEZIONE L
        WHERE C.CODCORSO = L.CODCORSO
        GROUP BY C.CODCORSO, MATRDOC) L
   WHERE DOC.TEACHERID = L.TEACHERID;
```

with this output:

```
TEACHERID   COURSEID    GVA
S12346      C9          40.3333
S12346      C3          213
S12346      C11         88
S12348      C7          123
S12348      C5          79
S12348      C13         82.5
```

[image: query output]

now I want to obtain the TEACHERID and COURSEID with max 'GVA', so I added at the end of the query:

```
   GROUP BY TEACHERID
   HAVING MAX(GVA)
```

but it doesn't work, I obtain these values:

```
TEACHERID   COURSEID    GVA
S12346      C9          40.3333
S12348      C7          123
```

Comment: What results do you want?  What database are you using?

Comment: Do you want 1 row or 1 row for each teacherid?

Comment: 1 row for each teacherid, I made a little explanation bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833871/2354957

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd that the average number of students is the "GVA", but okay.

In ANSI SQL you can use the `fetch first` clause:

```
SELECT C.CODCORSO AS COURSEID, MATRDOC AS TEACHERID, AVG(NUMSTUDENTI) AS GVA
FROM CORSO C JOIN
     LEZIONE L
     ON C.CODCORSO = L.CODCORSO
GROUP BY C.CODCORSO, MATRDOC
ORDER BY GVA DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Not all databases support `FETCH FIRST`.  Common alternatives include `SELECT TOP` and `LIMIT`.

EDIT:

If you want the maximum *per teacher* then use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT C.CODCORSO AS COURSEID, MATRDOC AS TEACHERID, AVG(NUMSTUDENTI) AS GVA,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TEACHERID ORDER BY AVG(NUMSTUDENTI) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM CORSO C JOIN
           LEZIONE L
           ON C.CODCORSO = L.CODCORSO
      GROUP BY C.CODCORSO, MATRDOC
     ) cl
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY GVA DESC;
```

This is all ANSI standard syntax, including the proper use of `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think this should work

```
   SELECT teacherid, courseid, max(gva) ------*****changed
   FROM (SELECT MATRDOC AS TEACHERID
         FROM DOCENTE
         WHERE MATRDOC NOT IN (SELECT MATRDOC
                               FROM CORSO
                               WHERE AREA <> 'BASI DI DATI')) DOC,
        (SELECT C.CODCORSO AS COURSEID, 
                MATRDOC AS TEACHERID, 
                AVG(NUMSTUDENTI) AS GVA
        FROM CORSO C, LEZIONE L
        WHERE C.CODCORSO = L.CODCORSO
        GROUP BY C.CODCORSO, MATRDOC) L
   WHERE DOC.TEACHERID = L.TEACHERID
   group by teacherid;  -----*********added
```